# use aggregators functions in laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-4

i have a sql query i want to run in laravel, this would be the final query that works in msql server

```
select MAX([formulas].[id]), 
MAX([formulas].[numero]), 
MAX([formulas].[nombre]), 
MAX([formulas].[idSeccionFormula]), 
MAX([nombreProducto]), 
MAX([formulas_equivalencias].[equivalencia]), 
MAX([productos].[coste]), 
[formulas_detalle].[id] 
from [formulas] inner join [formulas_detalle] on 
[formulas].[id] =[formulas_detalle].[idFormula] inner join
[formulas_equivalencias] on [formulas].[id] = [formulas_equivalencias].[idFormula] 
inner join 
[productos] on [formulas_detalle].[idProducto] =[productos].[id] 
where [idSeccionFormula] = 1 
group by [formulas_detalle].[id]
```

I have this in Laravel:

```
$formulas = new Formula();
$formulas = $formulas
->select('MAX([formulas.id])','MAX(formulas.numero)','MAX(formulas.nombre)','MAX(formulas.idSeccionFormula)', 'MAX(productos.nombreProducto)', 'MAX(formulas_equivalencias.equivalencia)', 'MAX(productos.coste)', 
                            'formulas_detalle.id')
                    ->join('formulas_detalle', 'formulas.id', '= ', 'formulas_detalle.idFormula')
                    ->join('formulas_equivalencias', 'formulas.id', '= ', 'formulas_equivalencias.idFormula')
                    ->join('productos', 'formulas_detalle.idProducto', '= ', 'productos.id');
```

But i am getting a Laravel error:

> The multi-part identifier "MAX([formulas.id])" could not be bound.

I have read how to use aggregators in laravel but i cannot used them in this case, i tried to use DB::raw(), but no luck.

I hope someone can know the answer to it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$forumulas = $formulas->join('formulas_detalle', 'formulas.id', '= ', 'formulas_detalle.idFormula')
                      ->join('formulas_equivalencias', 'formulas.id', '= ', 'formulas_equivalencias.idFormula')
                      ->join('productos', 'formulas_detalle.idProducto', '= ', 'productos.id')
                      ->select([
                                 DB::raw('Max(formulas.id) as id'),
                                 DB::raw('Max(formulas.numero) as numero'),
                                 DB::raw('Max(formulas.nombre) as nombre'),
                                 DB::raw('Max(formulas.idSeccionFormula) as idSeccionFormula'),
                                 DB::raw('Max(productos.nombreProducto) as nombreProducto'),
                                 DB::raw('Max(formulas_equivalencias.equivalencia) as equivalencia'),
                                 DB::raw('Max(productos.coste) as coste')
                               ])
                      ->get()
```

Comment: glad to hear that so you can accept my answer now :-p ?